# Downloading/playing static audio files on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone app that downloads multiple WAV files from the web, storing the resultant sound data on the phone for playback in the app.  Sometimes this works fine, and sometimes I'm getting one of two problems with the sound:

1) There are pieces of a downloaded sound file that play back as staticky, corrupted noise

2) Sometimes the full download doesn't appear to happen, meaning the binary data isn't recognizable as a legit sound file and chokes my playback library (FMOD), causing a crash.

I'm using an NSURLConnection to build up the data by appending data received from the connection, as described in Apple's docs.  My question is this: how can I write my downloading code so as to ensure that all files get downloaded and that they get downloaded without the corruption/noise?

**Facts:**

- The downloads are happening from Amazon S3.
- They are a maximum of around a half megabyte in size.
- They are not corrupted on the server -- i.e. they play back fine in a browser even when screwed up on the phone.

Below is the code I use to download all undownloaded files on each app launch.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
- (void)downloadOutstandingFileSounds{
    NSArray *theFiles = [File listOfDownloadableOpponentfiles];

    if ([theFiles count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Updating %d new files...", [theFiles count]);
        for (File *file in theFiles) {
            self.theFile = file;        
            NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:file.publicUrl] 
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                    timeoutInterval:60.0];
            NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
            if (theConnection) {
                currentFileDataContainer = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            }else {
                NSLog(@"failed attempt to download resource at: %@", file.publicUrl);
            }

        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"OutstandingFileSoundsDownloaded" object:self];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [currentFileDataContainer setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [connection release];
    [currentFileDataContainer release];

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSMutableData *)data{
    [currentFileDataContainer appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Success! Received %d bytes of file data", [currentFileDataContainer length]);
    self.theFile.fileSoundData = currentFileDataContainer;
    [self.theFile save];
    NSLog(@"Downloadable files count: %d", [[File listOfDownloadableOpponentfiles] count]);
    self.theFile = nil;
    [File clearCache];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything too wrong with your approach, but take a look at ASIHTTPRequest library http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ This can be used to queue up a number of downloads and manage the errors.

Comment: Oh cool.  I'd used ASI a bit but never needed it to solve a problem in this context. I like the operation queue aspect of ASI, but I think that its gzip support might be the real thing that could probably solve my problem here -- thanks for pointing me back to it.

Comment: BTW you seem to have asked a number of questions, but not accepted any answers. You should go back through what you have asked, and accept the correct answer (assuming there is one) : that's what this site is about!

Comment: Is that what the "Answer Your Question" button is meant to do?  I was looking for how to do that (accept).  I'll look harder.  :-)

ASI turned out to work for me to solve this.  I haven't looked at the code, but I suspect it just rescues errors better during the transfer.  The ASINetworkQueue class is very nice.  I'll definitely be using this library more often.  It's even got some tentative support for the S3 API baked right in!